# Convert result from PDO::fetchAll() to array like

Tags: php, database, arrays, string, pdo

I have a list of names from my database.

I'm trying to convert the result from the PDO::fetchAll() function to get a result like a string:

"name1","name2","name3" etc.

I don't know if you know what I mean.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Please provide a sample output of your query, anyway you will end using a good ol' `implode` function.

Comment: please edit your question to include the relevant parts of your code so someone can help you.

Comment: What is the destination for this `"name1","name2","name3"` string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the very [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#example-1022) manual page contains the code that lets you get 1-dimensional array which can be easily imploded

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

you could also use Mysql's `group_concat()` function to get the string already from SQL.

But it is critical to know the destination of the data.

Comment: Just a little note - FETCH_COLUMN really fetches only 1 column - "even though the SQL statement itself may return multiple columns per row"

Answer (score -1):

Found this, God knows where, a long time ago to accomplish this very task. I hope you find it helpful:

```
 /**
  * Formats a line (passed as a fields  array) as CSV and returns the CSV as a string.
  * Adapted from http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#87120
  */
function arrayToCsv( array &$fields, $delimiter = ';', $enclosure = '"', $encloseAll = false, $nullToMysqlNull = false ) {
    $delimiter_esc = preg_quote($delimiter, '/');
    $enclosure_esc = preg_quote($enclosure, '/');

    $output = array();
    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        if ($field === null && $nullToMysqlNull) {
            $output[] = 'NULL';
            continue;
        }

        // Enclose fields containing $delimiter, $enclosure or whitespace
        if ( $encloseAll || preg_match( "/(?:${delimiter_esc}|${enclosure_esc}|\s)/", $field ) ) {
            $output[] = $enclosure . str_replace($enclosure, $enclosure . $enclosure, $field) . $enclosure;
        }
        else {
            $output[] = $field;
        }
    }

    return implode( $delimiter, $output );
}
```

Comment: You're of course just *guessing* that the OP is interested in *CSV* output...

Comment: That's what he said, deceze

Comment: Ctrl+F, "CSV"... your answer is the only thing mentioning CSV on this page though...?!

Comment: Quoting OP (because someone clearly hasn't read): "I'm trying to convert the result from the PDO::fetchAll() function to get a result like a string: "name1","name2","name3" etc." That looks like a CSV to me.

Comment: It *looks like* CSV, but perhaps the OP just wants a one-dimensional *array*...